# reference request: Noetherianness generalization with non-monic arrows

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, category-theory

I have the following situation:
Let $C$ be a category and $X\in {ob}(C)$

Let $C_X$ denote the category whose objects are monic arrows into $X$ and whose morphisms are commuting triangles in $C$ (where the underlying morphism between the domains needs not be monic)

There's the following property of $X$:

The limit of any diagram $F:\mathbb{\omega}^{op}\rightarrow C_X$ exists, and is given by $F(n)$ for some $n\in\omega$ and all higher morphisms are identities

This generalizes classical Noetherianess of objects, that asserts the same, only in the category whose morphisms are monic triangles.

Is there a name for this generalization?

Comment: What you're describing would be a generalization of Artinianness rather than Noetherianness.

Comment: Also, I believe you mean "domains" rather than "codomains" in your second paragraph; the codomain of an arrow into $X$ would be $X$.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Right on domains, will fix
And I follow the nlab article, [link]https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/noetherian+object  where ascending chain of subobjects is Noetherianess (unlike rings)

Comment: What you have written here is not an ascending chain. $\omega$ is the poset of natural numbers, so it is an infinite ascending chain; $\omega^{op}$ on the other hand is a descending chain, and the limit of $F$ would be the intersection of the chain rather than its union.

Comment: In any case my answer is the same : your $C_X$ must have all its arrows monic, and in fact it will always be a preorder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding something, your proposed generalization is not actually a generalization; your property is equivalent to Artinianness (and not Noetherianness : you would need to replace the limit of $F: \mathbb{\omega}^{op} \rightarrow C_X$ by the colimit of $F:\mathbb{\omega}\rightarrow C_X$ for that).

Indeed, if I understand correctly the objects of your $C_X$ are monomorphisms, and an arrow between two objects $m:M\to X$ and $n:N\to X$ is an arrow $f:M\to N$ of $C$ such that $n\circ f=m$. You say that $f$ need not be monic, but in fact it always is in that case : if you have two arrows $u,v$ for which $f\circ u=f\circ v$, then
$$m\circ u=n\circ f\circ u=n\circ f\circ v=m\circ v,$$
and thus $u=v$ since $m$ is a monomorphism.

So actually your commuting triangles will always be monic triangles, so your property is in fact the same as Artinianness.

Comment: You are of course right, for some reason I misread the situation completely, as the triangles need not commute, I will edit the question shortly with more details, thanks for the help

Comment: The situation I had turned out to be as simple as you described, I may need some sleep :)